# presentingViewController:animated isn't working

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to use the camera API to take a picture but when I try using

```
[self presentingViewController:picker animated: YES];
```

I keep getting an error saying:

> No visible @interface for 'MainViewController' declares the selector 'presentingViewController:animated:'

and I can't seem to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localised. 

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic it is such an obvious problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be `[self presentModalViewController: picker animated: YES]` (now deprecated)

or `[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion: NULL];`

Check out the [`UIViewController` class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW29) for more details

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing like `presentingViewController: animated:` it's `presentModalViewController:  animated:` as @danielbeard suggested.

`presentingViewController` is a *read only* property that tells about:

"The view controller that presented this view controller. (read-only)" [From the doc.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/presentingViewController)