# Sending an e-mail in app?

Tags: ios, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am new to xcode, and am wondering how to send email in an app! My code is below, but I keep getting an error for the "self presentModalViewController" line. Is my code completely wrong? Or did I just forget to declare the selector, and how do I declare the selector? Someone please help me

```
     MFMailComposeViewController* controller          = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]         init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[controller setSubject:@"My Subject"];
[controller setMessageBody:@"Hello there." isHTML:NO];
if (controller)[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];


}
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller
  didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result
                error:(NSError*)error;
{
if (result == MFMailComposeResultSent) {
NSLog(@"It's away!");
}
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: The exact error you're getting would help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [presentingViewController:animated isn't working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380412/presentingviewcontrolleranimated-isnt-working)

Comment: presentModalViewController is deprecated.  You should stop using it.

Answer (score 0):

please present your mail composer using
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES];